# mongodb functions return format

Tags: mongodb

I defined a function in mongo, in my case to return me a collection of users (from my Users collection).
This is the function:

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id: "getUsers",
    value: function () {
        report = {};
        db.Users.find({})
            .projection({email: 1, account: 1, name: 1, phone: 1})
            .forEach((item) => {
                report[item._id] = { email: item.email, account: item.account, name:item.name, phone:item.phone }
            });
        return report;
    }
});
```

When I use db.getCollection('Users').find() I get as result multiple documents, each user on a separate document, something like:

```
/* 1 */ 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577b72bc421aa97934294614"),
    "name": "John"
}

/* 2 */ 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577b72bc421aa97934294700"),
    "name": "Ron"
}

/* 3 */
etc
```

When I run the function, I get only one document:

```
/* 1 */
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("577b72bc421aa97934294614"),
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("577b72bc421aa97934294700"),
        "name": "Ron"
    },
etc....
]
```

What my function should return in order to get the data as multiple documents? It is possible?

Comment: How exactly are you processing the result?

Comment: What do you mean my processing the result? Inside the function I return an array. I tried to return a dictionary, but doesn't return multiple documents.

Comment: Well, *you return an array*. That’s why you get an array. What else would you expect exactly? If you loop through that, you get individual documents one by one. If you want to have one collection of documents, that’s going to have to be something like an array.

Comment: The reason I asked the question is to find what I should return. I tried to return a dictionary, but when I call the function I get one document with my dictionary inside. What should I return from function in order to get multiple documents, like find() returns, when I call the function?

Comment: What function exactly? Something inside the Mongo shell? Or in some client programming language (nodejs, Python, something else?). Where do you want to return to? In general, returning from a function can only return a single value. If you want to return multiple documents in that single value it’s going to have to be a collection type like an array. Where and how exactly do you get those “separate documents”?

Comment: custom function, added with db.system.js.save(.......)

Comment: Put more clarifying information and code samples into the question.

Comment: Code added. Please reopen it.